# Remove generated always identity to a column for a table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with following schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATMs]
(
    [StartTime] DATETIME2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL 
          CONSTRAINT [DF_M360_ATMs_StartTime] DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()),
    [EndTime] DATETIME2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_M360_ATMs_EndTime] DEFAULT ('9999-12-31'),
    [ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationID] VARCHAR(35) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_M360_ATMs_ApplicationID] DEFAULT ('??????'),
    [ComputerNumber] SMALLINT NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ATMs_ComputerNumber] DEFAULT ((-1)),
    [SQLStatement] CHAR(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_M360_ATMs_SQLStatement] DEFAULT ('I'),
    [IsTriggered] BIT NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ATMs_IsTriggered] DEFAULT (1),  
    [Location] NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
```

I want to insert some test values into this table.

But I cannot insert value into 'StartTime' column as it has Generated always identity.

So I want to remove that identity and then insert some values into the table and add the identity again.

Can you please help me for removing identity or give any other solution to insert values into 'StartTime' column?

Comment: I went through MSDN on `Temporal table`. I don't think we can disable or override the property and insert our own values

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **default** for those columns? I think then you don't have to remove and add those columns again and again.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Department] ([DeptID] ,[DeptName] ,[ManagerID] ,
ParentDeptID], SysStartTime, SysEndTime)   
VALUES(11, 'Sales', 101, 1, default, default);
```

For more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591019.aspx